# Error reading from connection with big .RData file

Tags: r

In my current working directory, I have multiple .RData files saved. When I load them, everything goes fine, except for one.

Unlike the others, this file is pretty big (800 MB vs 20 MB average). Therefore, when I try `load("myfile.RData")`, R throws the error:

```
Error in load("myfile.RData") : 
  error reading from connection
```

As the the process of creation of the object saved in this file takes a lot of time, I would like to find a solution to load the .RData in the environment.

So far, I tried to increase R memory allocation, but it didn't work.

Does anyone have an idea?

Thanks!

Comment: I'm guessing that either (a) the computer used to create the `.RData` file has more ram, or (b) the current R session has more objects in it before loading it than when the rdata file was created, therefore exhausting ram. Or (c) the rdata file is on OneDrive or a network share or something else that is not strictly and purely local.

Comment: @r2evans a) I created the file and c) the file is saved locally so no issue there. I thought about b) and I tried to load the file in an empty environment, and the environment, plus the environment in which the file was created had loaded objects.

Comment: Okay, I don't know how I can help, sorry.